# How can I get the applicationsection from a customized config file?

Tags: c#, app-config, configuration-files, application-settings

I have a customized file configFile , and I need to read out the Property.Settings from the applicationConfig section in the file.

the configuration can be loaded in this way:

```
var localConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configFile);
```

I can find localConfig.AppSettings, but not localConfig.ApplicationSettings.

Is there a way to do so? thanks.